# Reading and returning jpg file in Python, ASP.NET?

Tags: python, asp.net, jpeg

I have an `image.asp` file, using Python, in which I am attempting to open a JPEG image and write it to the response so that it can be retrieved from the relevant link. What I have currently:

```
<%@ LANGUAGE = Python%>
<%

path = "path/to/image.jpg"

with open(path, 'rb') as f:
    jpg = f.read()

Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg"

Response.WriteBinary(jpg)

%>
```

In a browser, this returns the following error:

```
The image "url/to/image.asp" cannot be displayed because it contains errors.
```

I suspect the issue is that I am just not writing contents of the jpg file correctly. What do I need to fix?

Comment: Have you tried using a different file to test that its not image.asp that is broken?

Comment: @Puffycheeses How might it be broken?

Comment: Can you add the output of `curl -v <url>`

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is here:

```
 with open(url, 'rb') as f:
```

Your variable, that contains path is named path, not url.

Make it as:

```
 with open(path, 'rb') as f:
```

and it will work better.

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately that was just a name I had forgotten to change in tidying up the code for posting. (Now fixed.) The variable names match up in my script and the error remains.

Comment: Friend `call python exe with binary mode` **/.../.../python.exe -u** . So python automaticaly encoded (with default encoding(maybe ascii)) this response.. **Binary_output != Binary_input**

Comment: @dsgdfg Could you further explain what you mean? I don't quite understand.

Comment: `Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg"` Not a valid file response !  `<%@ LANGUAGE = Python%>` can provide  any BINARY operation ? Your question is fuzzy, But got 2 probality errors : 1 Wrong-Header 2-Wrong-Content. So how to figure "what is your problem?". Use wireshark for see full packet  definitions!

Comment: I forgot how to do it for a long time ago I went to use Linux, the old age... i am sorry.